# How can I reference command line arguments with nix build?

Tags: nix

Within my nix expression I have a line like:

```
myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nix "HaskellNixCabalStarter" (./.) {}
```

I'd like in some way, to pass a command line argument when running `nix build`, in which case the line should instead be:

```
(myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nixWithOptions "HaskellNixCabalStarter" (./.) "--enable-profiling" {})
```

How do I reference command line arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--arg name expr` [command line option](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sec-common-options) to pass a bool or other expression.

So you'll have

```
{ profiling ? false }:

# let myHaskellPackages = ... etc etc, whatever you already have
let profilingArg = if profiling then "--enable-profiling" else "";

in myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nixWithOptions "HaskellNixCabalStarter" (./.) profilingArg {}
```

and then

```
$ nix-build --arg profiling true
```

Alternatively you could expose the whole cabal option string allowing for example `--argstr cabalOptions '--enable-profiling -O2'`. Note `argstr` so you don't have to escape the string as a Nix string literal.